# model open is working but close function doesn't work in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am working on bootstrap modal openup, when i click on Edit button, it open the bootstrap modal, but when i click on close button it doesn't close the modal, can anyone please check my code, and help me what's issue in it ? Here i have added my code, can anyone please tell me why close modal is not working for that, on close button it calls `handleClose()` method of `Example Class` thanks for your help.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Button,OverlayTrigger, Tooltip,Popover} from 'react-bootstrap';



//var Modal = require('react-bootstrap-modal') //require('react-bootstrap-modal')  
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;  
//var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;  

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: false,
      //popup_index : this.props.popup_index
    };
  }

  handleClose() {
      //alert('sdsd');
      this.setState({ show : false });  
      //this.props.handleShow(this.state.show);
  }

  handleShow() {
      this.setState({ show: this.props.show });
  }  

  render() {
    const popover = (
      <Popover id="modal-popover" title="popover">
        very popover. such engagement
      </Popover>
    );
    const tooltip = <Tooltip id="modal-tooltip">wow.</Tooltip>;

    return (
      <div>

        <Modal show={this.props.handleShow} onHide={this.handleClose} >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading {this.props.popup_id} </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </p>

            <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={popover}>
                <a href="#popover">popover</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>

            <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip}>
                <a href="#tooltip">tooltip</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>  

            <hr />

            <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
            <p>
              Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
              dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
              ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
            </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class PalladiumHub extends React.Component {


  render() {

    return (<tr>
      <td>{this.props.keyuser}</td>
      <td>{this.props.name.name}</td>
      <td><button type="button" onClick={(e) => { this.props.editTask(this.props.index) }} >Edit</button><button onClick={(e) => { this.props.deleteTask(this.props.index) }}>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    )
  }
}  

class CallCRUD extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.editTask = this.editTask.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      isOpen: false,
      show : false,
      popup_index:''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  toggleModal(index) {
      this.setState({show:true,popup_index:index});    
  }


  deleteTask(index) {
    //alert(index);
    //console.log(index);
    //return false;
    let tasks = this.state.items;

    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      items: tasks
    })
  }

  editTask(index) {
    this.toggleModal(index);
    //console.log(index);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.items);
    return (
      <section>
          <table border="1"> <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th></tr> {
            this.state.items.map((data, index) => {
              //return console.log(data.id);
              return <PalladiumHub name={data} keyuser={data.id} index={index} key={index} deleteTask={this.deleteTask} editTask={this.editTask} /> 
            })
          }
          </table>
          <Example handleShow = {this.state.show} popup_id = {this.state.popup_index}  />
      </section>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    <CallCRUD />, document.getElementById('root')  
);
```

Comment: `<Modal show={this.props.handleShow} onHide={this.handleClose} >` change this to:
`<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose} >`

Comment: Now model open doesn't working

Comment: For modal open i have passed the parameter from parent to child, so we need this.props.handleShow

Comment: Just seeing the second part...would modify and put as an answer hold on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making this changes: **The change here is** : `this.handleClose`,
`<Example showModal={this.state.show} popup_id={this.state.popup_index}  handleClose={this.handleClose}/>`

```
class CallCRUD extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    this.editTask = this.editTask.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      isOpen: false,
      show : false,
      popup_index:''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  toggleModal(index) {
      this.setState({show:true, popup_index:index});    
  }
  handleClose(){
    this.setState({show: false});
  }

  deleteTask(index) {
    //alert(index);
    //console.log(index);
    //return false;
    let tasks = this.state.items;

    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      items: tasks
    })
  }

  editTask(index) {
    this.toggleModal(index);
    //console.log(index);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.items);
    return (
      <section>
          <table border="1"> <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th></tr> {
            this.state.items.map((data, index) => {
              //return console.log(data.id);
              return <PalladiumHub name={data} keyuser={data.id} index={index} key={index} deleteTask={this.deleteTask} editTask={this.editTask} /> 
            })
          }
          </table>
          <Example showModal={this.state.show} popup_id={this.state.popup_index}  handleClose={this.handleClose}/>
      </section>
    );
  }

}
```

Then to the Example component **The Major change here is**: `<Modal show={this.props.showModal} onHide={this.props.handleClose} >`, `<Button onClick={this.props.handleClose}>Close</Button>`

```
class Example extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const popover = (
      <Popover id="modal-popover" title="popover">
        very popover. such engagement
      </Popover>
    );
    const tooltip = <Tooltip id="modal-tooltip">wow.</Tooltip>;

    return (
      <div>

        <Modal show={this.props.showModal} onHide={this.props.handleClose} >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading {this.props.popup_id} </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
            </p>

            <h4>Popover in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={popover}>
                <a href="#popover">popover</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>

            <h4>Tooltips in a modal</h4>
            <p>
              there is a{' '}
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={tooltip}>
                <a href="#tooltip">tooltip</a>
              </OverlayTrigger>{' '}
              here
            </p>  

            <hr />

            <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
            <p>
              Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
              dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
              ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
            </p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.props.handleClose}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using props data to show/hide your Modal but you are managing state on handleClose so you shoult use this.state.show instead of this.props.show just change the code as below.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can you help me with code

Answer (score 1):

See you are passing this.state.show == true in handleShow.

So, now you need to make this.state.show == false on a close of modal.

To do so, make one function in the CallCRUD component:-

```
handleModal = () => {
  this.setState({
    show:false  
  }) 
}
```

Now, pass this function in a property to example component like this:

```
<Example handleShow = {this.state.show} handleClose={()=>{this.handleModal()}} popup_id = {this.state.popup_index}  />
```

Next, in Example component under the handleClose function write this:

```
this.props.handleClose();
```